# Need to run 50 selenium web drivers at the same time

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing

I need to simulate a team of about 50 users for my tests. Ive been using selenium so far but find that once I'm firing out more than 4 web drivers my results become more and more unstable and the result vary alot.
Is Selenium Grid the way to go or is there something else out there for what I need?

Comment: You should be using a Load testing tool  like Jmeter or Gatling and not UI testing tool like Selenium to achieve this.

Comment: A good starting point for setting up Jmeter with selenium will be - https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/leverage-your-load-testing-using-jmeter-and-selenium-webdriver/